# How to use include query in elastic search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I use own analzyer to asciifolding and lowercase. How Can I send query about this:

```
{
   
  "query": {
    
    "query":"*mil*"
}
```

When I didn't use own analzyer I could do, thanks QuerStringBuilder. Now it's not working.

I tried to find a Polish stammer but it's not there. Is there any other way out? I need to have my own analyzer to map accents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved problem. I changed .escape(true) to .escape(false) in my QuerStringBuilder.